# How to make the pdf contents not copyable using php?

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

Am using mpdf method to generate the pdf files. the contents in the pdf files are copyable. I want to make the pdf file contents not copyable. is there any way to do this in php coding?
I tried to convert the pdf file into image and then convert those images into pdf using imagemagick. but the second part of converting images into pdf gives me a pdf with pages that are not in a order... give me any solution to make the pdf files not copyable  please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set protection as described in the manual [like this](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=129&searchstring=protection)

"SetProtection – Encrypts and sets the PDF document permissions"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the underlying CPDF engine to specify what the user can do with the document. Per the CPDF documentation:

Calling the `setEncryption()` function sets up the document to be encrypted, this is the only way to mark the document so that they user cannot use cut and paste, or printing.

Using the call without options, defaults to preventing the user from cut & paste or printing. There are no passwords require to open the document.

Setting either off the passwords will mean that the user will have to enter a password to open the document. If the owner password is entered when the document is opened then the user will be able to print etc. If the two passwords are set to be the same (or the owner password is left blank) then there is no owner password, and the document  cannot be opened in the accesible mode.

The pc array can be used to allow specific actions. The following example, sets an owner password, a user password, and allows printing and cut & paste.

```
$pdf->setEncryption('trees','frogs',array('copy','print'));
```

Using the above example, with dompdf you would first render the document, then issue something along the lines of the following:

```
$dompdf->get_canvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption('trees','frogs',array('copy','print'));
```

you can also see detail [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dompdf-dev/IHnFkl7ejXw/wMFWFsNSStcJ)